# Tiny MCE Editor In iframe

Tags: iframe, tinymce

i have an html page in which i sue TinyMCE editor in iframe and i have a button which is out side the iframe. my problem is taht iwant to get the value of editor on button click but when i click the button i found nothing please help here is my code

Iframe Code:

```
<iframe id="EditorFrame" src="UploadTemplates.aspx" frameborder="0" style="height: 900px;
            width: 1000px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

UploadTemplates.aspx Code:

```
<div>
        <p>
            <textarea id="TemplateEditor" cols="50" rows="50" runat="server">
            </textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(function () {
    uploader = $("#TempateFileUploader");
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,
        width: "800",
        height: "640"
        //        setup: function (ed) {
        //            ed.onClick.add(function (ed, e) {
        //                alert('Editor was clicked: ' + e.target.nodeName);
        //            });
        //        }

    });

$("#Button1").click(function () {
        alert(tinymce().get("TemplateEditor").getCOntent());
    });

});
```

on the click of Button1 hsing Jquery i found nothing of TinyMCE althoug i found the object of tinyMCE but not able to get value please help how can i get the value of timyMCE out side the iframe on button click using jquery

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem might be to use `getContent()` instead of `getCOntent()` .
Using `getCOntent()` you should get javascript errors!!

Comment: i also use getContent() but the value is undefined

Comment: use tinymce.get("TemplateEditor") instead of tinymce().get("TemplateEditor") !